# Currency not saving the coins and i want to load the score

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, currency

Hello everybody i'm having an issue with the score and the currency thing, the game had a coins so the player can collect them so what i want to, the coins add to the currency text ,every time when i play automatically they increase what i took coins in the game and at the end to load and save the currency so when i re-open the game so i can see the collected coins doesn't changed

Here's the GameManager script

```
public Text scoreText, coinText, modifierText, hiscoreText;
private float score, coinScore, modifierScore;

    public void GetCoin()
{
    diamondAnim.SetTrigger("Collect");
    coinScore++;
    coinText.text = coinScore.ToString("0");
    score += COIN_SCORE_AMOUNT;
    scoreText.text = score.ToString("0");
}
```

Here's the shopPanel script

```
//test
public static int money = 0;
public Text coinsTxt;
public Text currencyTxt;
public static int totalMoney;

void Awake()
*{
         currencyTxt = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Coins");
}*
private void Update()
{
     coinsTxt.text = "Coins: " + currencyTxt;
    coinsTxt.text = "" + money;
}

void TotalMoney()
{
    money += totalMoney;
    currencyTxt.text = "" + totalMoney;
}
```

Coin script !

```
public class Coin : MonoBehaviour {

private Animator anim;

private void Awake()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}


private void OnEnable()
{
    anim.SetTrigger("Spawn");
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {

        //CurrencyManager.gameManager.AddMoney(1);
        GameManager.Instance.GetCoin();
        anim.SetTrigger("Collected");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There is no save code in your question. You didn't even bother to Google "how to save variable in Unity". There are many posts about PlayerPrefs out there

Comment: I read about playetPrefs and i tried some and didn't work so i erase them from the code ;)

Comment: No problem. Next time your code is not working, post the non working code and describe what you mean by "doesn't work". It will show people that you have tried something and they will use that code to help you. No need to erase it.

Comment: Okay so should i edit the code that i erased them ?

Comment: You don't have to. This question is closed. See the duplicate link for a better way to save data in Unity

Comment: I edited it , its not closed tho

Comment: And i read it yesterday , I'm not using Json i'm using C#

Comment: It is closed which means no one can answer it unless it is re-opened. Your second comment is funny. I think you should learn the difference between Json and C#. One is just a data format to save your file in and the other one  is a programming language

Comment: I read about Json before one hour , i have a question currency doesn't work what should i do ?

Comment: Hey, read the duplicate then try to do what's there. Edit your question with your new code and tell me which part is not working

Comment: It's in the code the shopPanel script which is currencyTxt

Comment: What i want is when player collect the coins , they appear in the currencyText which is in the shopPanel and every time when he play and collect coins the currency increase

Comment: I know it's been closed and quite old, but you're reading a PlayerPref you've never set in the first place. In GetCoin, you should set your playerpref after incrementing coinScore, then when you come to the shop panel and reading it, it'll be there.